# my api is not listing address, latitude and longitude

Tags: node.js, api

[[image]] here is my results[1][image: here is my data]
here my data

here I create my mongo schema  using mongoose

```
 const UserScheme = new mongoose.Schema({

     title:{
         type: String,
         required: true,

     },
     description:{
         type: String,
         required: false
     },
     email:{
         type: String,
          unique :true,
          required: true,
         lowercase: true
     },
```

everything seems right here

```
    address:{
         type: String,
         required: false,
         select: false
     },
     latitude:{
         type: Number,
         required:false,
          select: false
     },
    longitude:{
         type: Number,
         required:false,
         select: false
      },
      
     createdAt:{
         type: Date,
         default: Date.now,
     }, 
 })
```

my pre-save code

```
 UserScheme.pre('save', async function(next){
     const hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10)
     this.password = hash
```

here I geocode

```
    const code = await geocoder.geocode(this.address)
    console.log(this.address)
    console.log(code)
```

here I get the latitude and longitude

```
     if(Array.isArray(code)&&code[0]){
             this.latitude = code[0].latitude
             this.longitude = code[0].longitude
}
```

here is my list

```
 router.get('/list', async (req, res) =>{
     try{
         const users = await user.find()

         return res.send({users})
     }catch(err){
         console.log(err)
         return res.status(400).send({error: 'Error listing project'})
     }


 })
```

for some reason it isnt showing the address, latitude and longitude, can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select : false makes field values not accessible ,
remove it or make it , select : true.

```
 address:{
     type: String,
     required: false,
     select: true
 },
 latitude:{
     type: Number,
     required:false,
      select: true
 },
longitude:{
     type: Number,
     required:false,
     select: true
  },
```